# using AsynTask inside Adapter class

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter

I want to delete my Item from Custom List by clicking  on delete icon of the list. I used `remove()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` method for erasing it from my Layout. But When I am trying to send the id of the list through JSON, my app is getting crash.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ....
// Some of normal code ... working fine 
....
    holder.imv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            product2copy = product; // product is not getting recognized in Onpostexecution method ... coping it in the object declared as Instance 
            final int mitemid =Integer.parseInt(product.getId());

          //  boolean b = products.remove(product); I am putting it in post execution method

            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new CustomListCheckoutAdapter.ReadJSON3().execute("http://MyUrlhere/deleteditem.php?dish_id="+mitemid+"&uid=9155494233");    //1
                }
            });

/*  I am putting this in on onPostExecute method now ...
                if(b)
                {
                    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The value has deleted from Local",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    UpdateTotal();

                }
*/              
        }
    });

    return row;
}

private void UpdateTotal() {
    int i = getCount();
    int t = 0;
    String tt;
    for (int j=0;j<i ; j++){
        Checkout_product p = getItem(j);  
     tt= p.getPrice();
        if(tt==null)
            tt="0";
        t = t + Integer.parseInt(tt);
    }
    tvt.setText(Integer.toString(t));
}

private static class MyItemHolder{

    TextView tetName;
    TextView txtquant;
    TextView txtprice;

    ImageView imv;

}


// The ReadJSON2 class ..........

class ReadJSON3 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        boolean b = products.remove(product2copy); //product - is not recognized

        if(b)
        {
            notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"The value has deleted from Local and in database too",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            UpdateTotal();

        }

       //super.onPostExecute(s);

    }
    private String readURL(String theURL) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theURL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android app.Activity

I am actually not getting it properly :) I will be glad if any one explain me about the exact problem apart from the solution.

I have made some of change in code after implementing AsyncTask. but I tried to explained it in comment using ... // or  /*  */ please help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(...)
```

Probably you are passing **`Application Context`** instead of your `Activity context`

Comment: Thanks, but actually my concept about this, is not so clear can you help me to understand it.  When and where I should use it? :)

Comment: oh, You mean this, -final CustomListCheckoutAdapter adapter = new CustomListCheckoutAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_final,arrayList , tv1
            );  //  what I called from Activity class

Comment: Are you pointing to - getApplicationContext()  ? what I should do now :)

Comment: try calling only `getContex()`

Comment: getContex() is not excepting. As  I am using the adapter statement inside a onPostExecute() method, as the list is getting created through JSON data only. other option is getBaseContex() that is also not working.

Comment: then you need to pass activity context inside of your `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

((Activity) context)yo should pass the Activity context! btw is so weird you use runOnUiThread but then you use an asynctask internally... there're better ways to handle what you want.

Comment: What is the better way ? Can you share that ? of course I will go to better way :)

Comment: i don't know what are you trying to do but acually you are doing this
doOnMainthread(doOnotherthread(jsonstuff)) --> is the same doing this: 
doOnotherthread() and if you need a "callback" use an interface or something like that